# Meteor error handling

Tags: javascript, meteor

How is it possible to add a global exception / error handler in Meteor.js. I looked through so much code, but noone explains a global method... Every one just do a try catch around every Meteor.call or add a async callback to it. But I'm lazy I just want one piece of code that handles all my Meteor.Errors. Mostly it's already a client readable error. So I just have to show it to him.

I tryed to use:

```
$(window).error(function(error) {
  const errorText = T9n.get("Exception." + error.originalEvent.error.error);
  View.toast(errorText);
});
```

but its just working for normal javascript errors not for Metero.Error.. seems to be that Meteor catches it, before I can catch it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is exactly what you need but, here is a solution.

In every Meteor.call(), have it like this:

```
Meteor.call('contactForm', arg1, arg2, function(err, res){
    handleError(err, res);
});
```

Define a reusable error handler in your client side:

```
handleError = function (err, res){
    if(err){
        //do something with the error sent from server. not the ugly alert() like this code.
        alert('error!')
    } else{
        //do something if no errors.
        alert('done!')
    }
}
```

Of course, you have to define your errors and results in your methods but this solves writing the same things over and over again in client side. You can also define helpers like handleError above in your server side. For example, I have `checkUser()` in my server like this:

```
checkUser = function (){
    if(!Meteor.user()){
        throw new Meteor.Error(400, 'You are not a unicorn yet! I mean, user.')
    }
}
```

and in methods I just write `checkUser();` to use it.

**EDIT:**
Those global functions are not inside any other code block. Just have them standalone

Comment: Yeah thats the standard way how to use meteor. you have to add to every call the handleError. But when you forget one error handling you are fu**ed up to find this code. And also the call will be asynchron when you add the callback function. I'm looking for an global solution that i dont have to add the errorhandling to every call.

Comment: hmm I understand now. Sorry then, I don't know.